# Can I do more than 1 ID?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I have been working on this for a couple days while rounding out some other issues popping up in my project. Below is the code I am using for it to respond to certain users with a different command. Is there a way I can create a file with discord user ID's and then have the command file read it?

```
if (message.author.id === "ID_HERE") {
}
```

I cant seem to figure out how to get it in another file and still read the ID

Answer (score -3, accepted):

What you can do is create a .txt file, and paste each userid separated by newlines. Something like this:
userid
userid2
userid3
(Where userid is the long line of numbers)
Here's the code for reading that .txt file and using it in that if statement.

```
const fs = require('fs');  
var userids = fs.readFileSync('nameoffile.txt').toString().replace(/\r\n/g,'\n').split('\n');
client.on("message", async message => {
if (userids.includes(message.author.id)) {
// do stuff
}
})
```

What that does is read the .txt file, set it as an array of userid values, and check if the message.author is part of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using file I/O, you can use arrays like this:

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "3"]

if (array.includes(message.author.id)) {
  // Do something
}
```

You can even programmatically manipulate the array to remove or add things easily.

A longer way to do this is:

```js
if (message.author.id === "1" || message.author.id === "2" || message.author.id === "2") {
  // Do something
}
```

If you *have* to do it with a file, first import the `fs` module with `const fs = require("fs");`, then read `file.txt` (or wherever you store your IDs), split it by a delimiter (like `\n`), and *then* use that array.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

// ...

var array;

fs.readFileSync("file.txt", function(data, err) { // Remember to replace "file.txt" with the name of the file
  if (err) throw err;
  array = data.split("\n"); // If IDs in file are separated with the newline character, \n
})

if (array.includes(message.author.id)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, With some editing and getting it to work for some reason I am ending up with the error "Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined" @GalaxyCat105

Comment: @TTGS7 This is because the array is not being initialized. Although you've already accepted an answer, try `var array = [];` instead of `var array;`. Does that remove the error? If yes, then it's a problem inside the callback of `fs.readFileSync`.